# Angular 6 update a component from the service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, publish-subscribe

I'm using angular 6 and I need to update the component when I call a service method. I have a variable `agent`that keep the selected agent from html so I get this variable from several component and I can delete this agent from a specific button.
When I call deleteAgent I have to update the interface so I need a way to "tell" to the component that the agent was deleted.

```
export class ComponentService {
  private agent : Agent
  constructor() { }

   /************ AGENT MANAGEMENT *****************/
   get getAgent(){
     return this.agent;
   }

   setAgent(agent: Agent){
     this.agent = agent;
   }

   deleteAgent(){
     this.agent = null;
     //inform the component about the change
   }
}
```

I read about ReplaySubject but I don't know if it is the correct way and how to remove element. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could store the agent instance in an Observable and than subscribe in the component to that observable.

```
export class ComponentService {
private _agent = Subject<Agent>();
constructor() { }

 /************ AGENT MANAGEMENT *****************/
 get agent(){
   return this._agent.asObservable();
 }

 set agent(agent: Agent){
   this._agent.next(agent);
 }

 deleteAgent(){
   this.agent = null;
 }
}
```

Comment: A Subject is great, and if you need to be able to subscribe to the `_agent` "after the fact" and receive the previous value, you can convert to a BehaviorSubject.

Comment: How can I retrieve the actual agent without the subscribe? In some case I need to retrieve the update by subscribe, in other case I need only the current agent

Comment: You can use a BehaviorSubject, this kind of subject does always hold one instance. Either you subscribe, use the value and unsubscribe. Or you call .value and get the current value. Both possible.

Comment: With behaviorSubject I have problem with subscribe on the first null value. FurthermoreI recive even the setAgent event and not only the deleteAgent

Comment: You could do something like this.agent.pipe(skip(1), filter(x => x === null))

Answer (score -1):

I resolved with this code, I don't know if it is the best code:

```
export class ComponentService {
  private agent: Agent;
  // Observable navItem source
  agentChange = new ReplaySubject<Agent>(1);

  constructor() { }

   /************ AGENT MANAGEMENT *****************/
   get getAgent(){
     return this.agent;
   }

   setAgent(agent: Agent){
     this.agent = agent;
   }

   deleteAgent(){
     this.agentChange.next(this.agent);
     this.agent = null;
   }
}
```

then in the custroctor of component I have the subscribe and the unsubscribe into destroy method:

```
this.componentService.agentChange.subscribe((agent:Agent)=>{
     //on success instruction
    })

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.componentService.agentChange.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: you are holding the instance of agent twice. That is not necessary and does not increase readability of the code.

Comment: I suggest to remove this.agent, it is not needed.